# SE Data Explorer Copy/Paste keyboard shortcuts missing

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Windows has 2 sets of Copy/Cut/Paste shortcuts by default. The most common of course are `Ctrl-C/X/V` but `Ctrl-Insert`, `Shift-Insert` and `Shift-Delete` are also Copy/Paste/Cut respectively.

I've been using the latter set since they were [available in MSDOS EDIT](http://www.pcxt-micro.com/keyboard.html)

In any case, the latter set don't work in the SE Data Exchange query editor. In fact, worse than doing nothing, pressing Shift-Insert toggles typeover - so when you do press CTRL-V, it pastes over the top of your query.

I'd suggest the functionality should be replicated (at least for Windows users - not sure if this is common on Mac/Linux).